# Proxy Server Multiple IP's

Tags: networking, server, proxy

Hello I am want to host a lot of SOCK5 proxies and would like to know is there any software/Linux build that could suit for hosting proxies for a while sub net on once instance. So I want roughly 256 ipv4's on one machine, what's the best way of doing this?

I have looked into Dante but would like to know if there is there any better software multiple proxies?

Comment: "I am want to host a lot of SOCK5 proxies" - you want to hide clients from lan side with one public ip? Or you want to have 256 in address and one public for put put? Or you want 1 in and 256 out addresses?  You wish only to hide clients or you wish cache traffic? Please be more precise.

Comment: I have 256 IP's on one dedicated server I would like to use them all on one interface and use the whole IP block but with unique authentication to each IP.

Answer (score 3):

Good. Lets start :)
Try this, should work for you.

First, solution is based on [squid](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Squid).

After installation, obviously, we’ll be modifying the `squid.conf` file. We’ll be using the following configuration directives:

```
http_port
name=
myportname
acl
http_access
tcp_outgoing_address
```

First, we want to tell Squid what IPs and ports to listen on, and we want to use the `name=` option with `http_port`:

```
# Squid normally listens to port 3128
http_port xx.xxx.xxx.111:3128 name=3128
http_port xx.xxx.xxx.112:3129 name=3129
http_port xx.xxx.xxx.113:3130 name=3130
http_port xx.xxx.xxx.114:3131 name=3131
http_port xx.xxx.xxx.115:3132 name=3132
http_port xx.xxx.xxx.116:3133 name=3133
```

We just asked Squid to listen on sequential ports and to designate a name for each inbound connection.  Now that we’ve named the inbound connections, we can designate an `ACL` based on each inbound connection name and assign an outgoing `IP` to each:

```
acl tasty3128 myportname 3128 src yy.yyy.yyy.0/24
http_access allow tasty3128
tcp_outgoing_address xx.xxx.xxx.111 tasty3128

acl tasty3129 myportname 3129 src yy.yyy.yyy.0/24
http_access allow tasty3129
tcp_outgoing_address xx.xxx.xxx.112 tasty3129

acl tasty3130 myportname 3130 src yy.yyy.yyy.0/24
http_access allow tasty3130
tcp_outgoing_address xx.xxx.xxx.113 tasty3130

acl tasty3131 myportname 3131 src yy.yyy.yyy.0/24
http_access allow tasty3131
tcp_outgoing_address xx.xxx.xxx.114 tasty3131

acl tasty3132 myportname 3132 src yy.yyy.yyy.0/24
http_access allow tasty3132
tcp_outgoing_address xx.xxx.xxx.115 tasty3132

acl tasty3133 myportname 3133 src yy.yyy.yyy.0/24
http_access allow tasty3133
tcp_outgoing_address xx.xxx.xxx.116 tasty3133
```

That’s it. You should now be able to connect to any configured IP addresses through Squid.

In example I use only 6 ip.

Next. If you wish basic authentication you must do following

We are going to create a file to store passwords in it and change the ownership of it so Squid can access.

```
sudo touch /etc/squid/passwd
sudo chown squid /etc/squid/passwd
```

Suppose that `john` is our username for accessing the Squid proxy server, we will use this command to generate password for that username. You will need to type the password and retype it again for confirmation. 
The `-d` argument in this command will force the `htpasswd` to use `CRYPT` encryption of the password.

```
sudo htpasswd -d /etc/squid/squid_passwd john
New password:
Re-type new password:
Adding password for user john
```

To test if the username and password type this command and in the following file enter the username and password seprated by space.

```
/usr/lib64/squid/ncsa_auth /etc/squid/passwd
john pass
OK
```

Open the Squid configuration file and add following lines to the top of file.

```
auth_param basic program /usr/lib64/squid/ncsa_auth /etc/squid/passwd
auth_param basic children 5
acl ncsa_users proxy_auth REQUIRED
http_access allow ncsa_users
https_access allow ncsa_users
```

After changes restart service

```
sudo service squid restart
```

Try.

Comment: It seems that Squid is only a can connect to HTTP and SOCKS is still in development. I have found SS5 and may have to use Dante but not sure which is the best for authentication.

Comment: I have problem setting up more than 128 ips with this metho coud you take a look on this post?
http://askubuntu.com/questions/903897/cannot-assign-more-than-128-outgoing-ips-with-squid3

Comment: https://www.tastyplacement.com/squid-proxy-multiple-outgoing-ip-addresses