# Cannot assign more than 128 outgoing IPs with squid3

Tags: networking, server, proxy, squid

I am using `squid 3.3.8`. I am setting up multiple outgoing IPs based on this post

[Proxy Server Multiple IP's](https://askubuntu.com/questions/680246/proxy-server-multiple-ips)

and this one

https://www.tastyplacement.com/squid-proxy-multiple-outgoing-ip-addresses

However, the problem is I have 256 outgoing IPs but squid acts as only first 128 rules were in effect. The configuration is fine because if I comment out first 128 rules then the last 128 ones work correctly. Any ideas?

EDIT:

I think my problem is the same as in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40102777/squid-max-number-of-ips-limited-to-128

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research I found out the solution, however it comes with a cost. First thing first yes there is a limit of 128 connections. Let me quote

> For each packet read Squid has to check the listening port list to see
>   if it is a read() or accept() operation. Doing even 128 checks per
>   packet is pushing the boundaries for reasonable performance loss.

So that's why the limit is there. If you want to remove it well you can do it by building the latest version of Squid using: 
`./configure CXXFLAGS="-DMAXTCPLISTENPORTS=XXX"`
where XXX is your new limit

Answer based on:
http://squid-web-proxy-cache.1019090.n4.nabble.com/squid-with-multiple-ips-is-listenting-to-some-ips-with-port-and-not-all-of-ips-td4668784.html